# Sqlite for graph database (embeddable)

Tags: database, graph, sqlite

after using sqlite3 in a project I stumbled across the concept of graph databases which is really more helpful for my usecase. 
I googled around a little bit but didn't find any embeddable graph database with Go bindings. 
Can anyone help out?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Today I read about cayley.io which seems to be embeddable in Golang according to [this repository](https://github.com/oren/embed-cayley).

Any thoughts about it?